# How to handle primary key in child table which is also primary and foreign key in parent table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, database-design

How can I create a relationship in EF core where the child(FullName) table has DrugId which is the primary key. In the parent table(Basic Data), DrugId is foreign key. But there are other child tables and they are also referring DrugId in the parent table as a foreign key. How can I create this relationship in C# ef core? One way is to create one dedicated foreign key column for every child table but it will make duplicate DrugId in the parent table. for example:

Parent Table:

```
 public int DrugId {get;set;}
 public int FullNameDrugId {get; set;}
 public int DataInfoDrugId {get; set;}
 public int FormCode {get;set;}
```

FullName Table:

```
 public int DrugId {get;set;}
 public string name {get;set;}
```

DataInfo Table:

```
 public int DrugId {get;set;}
 public string Size {get;set;
```

In the parent table, DrugId and FullNameDrugId, and DataInfoDrugId are the same.

I want to get data from the parent id using LINQ and include the other two tables just adding "Include" statement. I want to navigate from parent table to child. Now how can I deal with this?

Just focus on basic data and fullName table
[image]

Comment: So as I understand for one drug record there is only one full name record?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: @Eldar Yes. How can I connect these tables so that I can navigate through Linq? I mean it could be more table referring to BasicData table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would suggest using PKs to reference the other one-to-one related tables  so your tables and relation configuration should look like the below:

```
public class DrugBase
{
 [Key]
 public int DrugId {get;set;}
 public int FormCode {get;set;}

 public virtual DetailInfo DetailInfo {get;set;} // navigation properties
 public virtual DataInfo DataInfo {get;set;} // navigation properties
}

public class DetailInfo
{
 [Key]
 public int DrugId {get;set;} // PK
 public string Name {get;set;}
 
 public virtual DrugBase DrugBase {get;set;} // navigation properties
 // you can add any navigation property that DrugBase entity has
 // This might make it easier to write some queries easier
 // It allows you writing queries that don't reference DrugBase entity
}

public class DataInfo 
{
 [Key]
 public int DrugId {get;set;} // PK
 public string Size {get;set;
 
 public virtual DrugBase DrugBase {get;set;} // navigation properties
}
```

And you can configure them like below :

```
builder.Entity<DrugBase>();
            pihd.HasKey(r => r.DrugId);
            pihd.HasOne(r => r.DetailInfo)
               .WithOne(r => r.DrugBase)
               .HasForeignKey<DetailInfo>(r => r.DrugId)
               .HasPrincipalKey<DrugBase>(r => r.DrugId);

builder.Entity<DrugBase>();
            pihd.HasKey(r => r.DrugId);
            pihd.HasOne(r => r.DataInfo)
               .WithOne(r => r.DrugBase)
               .HasForeignKey<DataInfo>(r => r.DrugId)
               .HasPrincipalKey<DrugBase>(r => r.DrugId);
```

Comment: Excellent! That's what I wanted! One more thing I have BaseEntity and IAggregateRoot on BasicData/DrugBase. The Id in BaseEntity is no longer PK. So should I keep it as it is? If I remove BaseEntity then I have to remove IAggregateRoot too because of this I cannot create the repository of DrugBase. Any solution?

Comment: Keep in mind that all data in DrugBase is coming from file and I am using seeder. User cannot add or update this table data.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq I wasn't aware that your table has PK named Id, what I was trying to say is to create relations based on PKs and you don't need to add another property for this, just use the existing one. So you won't need any changes to keep your repositories intact.

Comment: I got it. I just removed DrugId and I am using Id which is in EntityBase as DrugId. So now it's good. Thank you. You save my lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Many-To-One relationship where several BasicData could refer to the same Drug, where the relationship between Drug and other tables like FullName that share the DrugId as a PK would be a One-to-One.

Using explicit mapping for the relationships:

// Drug (EF Core)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Drug>(e =>
{
    e.HasOne(x => x.FullName)
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

// Basic Data

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BasicData>(e =>
{
    e.HasOne(x => x.Drug)
        .WithMany()
        .IsRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.DrugId);
});
```

By default when using `HasOne()`.`WithOne()` it will join on the PKs of both tables.

Then to get to the drug's full name from a given BasicData query:

```
var data = _context.BasicDatas
    .Where( /* criteria */)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DrugId = x.Drug.Id, (Assuming using Id as PK in Drug)
        DrugName = x.Drug.FullName.Text
    }).ToList();
```

... To get the idea of how to leverage the relationship. If loading the entities themselves then eager load using `.Include(x => x.Drug).ThenInclude(x => x.Fullname)`  (Assuming EF Core)

Comment: BasicData and FullName exactly have one to one relationship. BasicData has information about drug and full name of drugs is in the FullName table. How can create a relationship without using Fleint API.

Comment: As mentioned, A one-to-one relationship will join using the PKs on both tables. You can configure it to use an alternative to the PK on one side, but that does require explicit configuration. If there is no Drug table/entity why use a DrugId rather that just BasicData's ID? To configure relationships that conform to standard normalization that EF understands you can use either fluent configuration or in most cases Attributes. For One-to-One or Many-to-One you would nominate the other side of the relationship using `[InverseProperty]` where you have navigation properties on both sides.